# Time bounded function with partial result in Haskell

Tags: haskell, timeout

An initial value (x), function (f), a predicate (p) and a time bound (t) is given. I want to apply 'f' repeatedly on x till it satisfies the 'p'. But on the same time wanna make sure it doesn't exceeds time limit. If time exceeds 't', it should return the partial result i.e., a pair of a number 'n' and value of applying 'f' n-times on 'x', for the largest n for which it actually performed the computation.

If partial result condition is relaxed, this can be easily programmed as -

```
import System.Timeout

iter :: a -> (a -> a) -> (a -> Bool) -> Int -> IO (Maybe (Int, a))
iter x f p t = do
  let fs = x:(map f fs)
  timeout t $ return $! head $ filter (\x -> p $ snd x) $ zip [1..] fs
```

I want it to have signature similar to -

```
iter :: a -> (a -> a) -> (a -> Bool) -> Int -> IO (Either (Int, a) (Int, a))
```

With Left for partial result and Right for complete result.

An silly and trivial example use of above function is -

```
*Main> iter 1 (+2) (> 1000000) 1000000
Just (500001,1000001)
*Main> iter 1 (+2) (> 1000000) 100000
Nothing
```

I want the second call to return partial computed result. Is there a simple way to do it?

More practical examples can be Newton–Raphson method or gradient descent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it is simplest to delegate such tasks to libraries with better abstraction capability than that offered by `base`, e.g. [`async`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.1.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html):

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-} 

import Control.Concurrent.Async 
import Control.Concurrent 

iter :: a -> (a -> a) -> (a -> Bool) -> Int -> IO (Either (Int, a) (Int, a))
iter z f p maxt = do 
  o <- newMVar (0, z)
  let loop old@(!i,x) = do 
        modifyMVar_ o (const $ return old)
        if p x then return old else loop (i+1, f x)
  race (threadDelay maxt >> readMVar o) (loop (0, z))
```

`race` takes two `IO` actions and returns whichever completes first, killing the other. The left action completes only if the maximum time has elapsed, and that thread is able to read the `MVar`. Since the other thread holds the `MVar` for a short period of time (while it is writing the result) the worker will never be interrupted while writing the result.

Note also that the only thing that forces the chain of applications `f $ f $ f..` is the predicate `p` - if you pass a lazy function (e.g. `const False`) then this will not work as you want. In practice there are few cases when you would use such a function (esp. with numeric computing), so it likely won't be of much concern. But in this case `loop` does no actual work and builds a ridiculously large number amount of applications:

```
>iter 2 (\x -> x * x) (const False) (10^6)
Left (472190,Interrupted.
```

My computer will never be able to print this result because it has [6.8×10^142142 digits](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E2%5E472190). However:

```
>iter 2 (\x -> x * x) (<0) (10^6)
Left (24,Interrupted
```

This is a small number with only about [5,000,000 digits](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E2%5E24).

Answer (score 2):

I believe your best bet is to use an `IORef` to keep track of the current computation state. Even if the computation is interrupted, its side effects won't be undone. Be sure to use just *one* `IORef` for both the counter and the current value; otherwise they could go out of sync in case of a timeout.

I'm not at all experienced with asynchronous code in Haskell, so take this with a grain of salt, but it seems to work.

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module IterTimeout where
import Control.Applicative
import Data.IORef
import System.Timeout

iter :: a -> (a -> a) -> (a -> Bool) -> Int -> IO (Either (Int, a) (Int, a))
iter x f p t = do
  ref <- newIORef (0, x)
  result <- timeout t (iterStep f p ref)
  maybe (Left <$> readIORef ref) (return . Right) result

iterStep :: (a -> a) -> (a -> Bool) -> IORef (Int, a) -> IO (Int, a)
iterStep f p ref = go
  where
    go = do
      old@(!oldCount, oldVal) <- readIORef ref
      if p oldVal
        then return old
        else writeIORef ref (oldCount + 1, f oldVal) >> go
```

Comment: You definitely want to use `atomicModifyIORef'` here or just use `MVar`s properly, this currently has a race condition otherwise, we can kill this thread midway through writing to the `IORef`.

Comment: @jozefg, I read through the "Memory Model" section of the documentation, which attempts to explain this, and I found it rather opaque. It looks like the difference is more about what operations can be reordered, right? So the only potential problem with the non-atomic versions here (if I'm understanding correctly) is that you might not get the very last value in case of an interrupted computation.

Comment: There's no way to "partially write" an `IORef`, since it only contains a single pointer.

Comment: OTOH, if it can do something awful like just returning the very first value, then the atomic versions are definitely the way to go. I don't know enough about it.

Comment: It would probably be simpler not read from the `IORef` in `iterStep`. Just pass the parameters along as normal function parameters. I'm almost certain this would be more efficient than reading from the `IORef` anyways.

Comment: @user2407038, could reordering end up causing the partial result reported be one other than the last (at worst, the first)?

Comment: @dfeuer I don't see how the writes could be re-ordered, unless the compiler for some reason decided to optimize away the writes altogether. Each write has a branch in between (`if p oldVal ..`), in general there is no way to tell if there even will even be any writes to reorder at all! I don't think the compiler would move the writes past a call to a recursive function either. Even if there weren't these natural barriers in the code, I think `atomicWriteIORef` would do it.

Comment: @dfeuer If you wanted to make this really robust, I think that the worker thread would need a lock which it releases between every iteration, and at the end of the timeout the main thread (instead of killer the worker directly) waits on the lock, then kills the worker (the `async` library would probably help quite a bit here).

Comment: @user2407038, that may be "robust" in one sense, bit doesn't guarantee that the worker dies in a timely fashion.